# how to add display order on custom post type? wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm trying to order my custom post type (sponsorship/sponsors) on a custom post (specific events page). However, I am not quite sure how to do this. I have downloaded Post order type plugin. When I tried using the Post Order Type Plugin, I was only able to drag and drop the order on the main Sponsors backend/dashboard page (where all the sponsors are listed). When I changed the order there, it changes the sponsors order in the specified event page in correspondence to the order on the main Sponsors page. However, I want to be able to change the order directly on the specific Event's page, because each event should have a different, specific order for its event. I also downloaded Toolset, but not sure if this can help.

[backend dashboard of specifying event page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8GMx.png) Please see attached picture of the backend dashboard of a sample event page. Post Title is the number ID of a specific Sponsor. Sponsors is a list of the name of the sponsor.

Any suggestions on how to do this? How to make it so I can display the sponsors in the order I want it to appear? There are 2 custom post types: Sponsors and Events. I am trying to output sponsors with a specific order to the event details page.

```
 <?php 
      // get event sponsorship list
      $sponsorship_object = types_child_posts('sponsorship');
        if (count($sponsorship_object) != 0) {
    ?>
      <div class="container event-sponsors text-center">
        <p class="partners_band_title">Event Sponsors</p>
    <?php

    // extract sponsor ids
    $sponsors = array();
    foreach($sponsorship_object as $sponsor_object) {
      $sponsors[$sponsor_object->post_title] = 
    wpcf_pr_post_get_belongs($sponsor_object->ID, 'sponsors'); 
    }


    // ensure array is ordered by key
    ksort($sponsors);

    // query sponsors; orderby is required to ensure data is return in the 
    same order we gave it
        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'sponsors',  'post__in' => $sponsors 
    , 'orderby' => 'post__in', 'posts_per_page' => -1); 
        $sponsor_loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $sponsor_loop->have_posts() ) {
      $sponsor_count = 0;
            while ( $sponsor_loop->have_posts() ) {

                $sponsor_loop->the_post();



      echo '<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 text-
    center">';
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url( get_post_meta($post->ID, 
    'wpcf-sponsor_website', true) ).'" 
    target="_blank">'.wp_get_attachment_image( 
    get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'big-thumbs' ).'</a>';
            echo '</div>';

        $sponsor_count++;
      /*if ($sponsor_count % 5 == 0) {
        echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-1 col-lg-1"></div>';
        echo '</div>';
      }*/
                }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
?>
      </div>
<?php>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be trying to order by three separate things:

- A key, in the line with `ksort`.
- The, "same order," according to the comment, which is probably the order enforced by the `ksort`.
- The desired order, from your plugin.

From what I can tell of their documentation, this plugin uses `menu_order` (which seems to be the most common WP way).

Your easiest solution would probably be to change `orderby` in your query arg array to `menu_order` (see [the Codex docs for `WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters)). That arg does accept an array so if you wish to preserve your existing sorting as the secondary key you may use `['menu_order', 'post__in']` as your `orderby` arg.

Try replacing your line with this:

```
$args = array
    'post_type' => 'sponsors',
    'post__in' => $sponsors,
    'orderby' => ['menu_order', 'post__in'],
    'posts_per_page' => -1
);
```

Comment: I changed it to this, and it does not display in the correct order! any other ideas on how to solve this?